# afterUpdate event typeORM - NestJS

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I would like to insert an entry in another table after each update of my data (log table)
I've created an EntitySubscriberInterface to do this.
The event is correctly triggered but my entity array don't include the id which is updated.

```
 async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
    console.log(event.entity);
    const book = event.entity;// entity should be a book
    const authorId = book.authorId;
    console.log(newAuthorId);       
// this.myService.insertHistory(authorId , event.entity);
```

}

If anybody have an idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With afterInsert method you have this information.
With afterUpdate you have to query the databse to get your entity.

```
const lot = await event.connection
      .getRepository(book)
      .findOne(event.entity.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either run a findOne query like @Bramovic44 suggests, alternatively you could setup a **afterLoad** which is basically called after a entity is loaded from the database

Minimal Reproduction below

```
export class EntitySubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<SomeEntity> {
  someEntity: SomeEntity;

  listenTo() {
    return SomeEntity;
  }

  afterLoad(someEntity: SomeEntity) {
    this.someEntity = someEntity;
  }

  async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<SomeEntity>): Promise<any> {
    event.entity; // returns updated properties in entity
    this.someEntity; // returns entity prior to update with all properties
  }
```